Assign static IP to Kubevirt VM pod
I'm trying to assign a static IP address to a Kubevirt VM pod. My goal is to be able to access the pod using the static IP over the network outside of Kubernetes. Here's my config:
apiVersion: kubevirt.io/v1
kind: VirtualMachine
metadata:
  name: testvm
spec:
  running: false
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        kubevirt.io/size: small
        kubevirt.io/domain: testvm
    spec:
      domain:
        devices:
          disks:
            - name: containerdisk
              disk:
                bus: virtio
            - name: cloudinitdisk
              disk:
                bus: virtio
          interfaces:
          - name: default
            bridge: {}
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 512M
      networks:
      - name: default
        multus:
          default: true
          networkName: bridge-test
      volumes:
        - name: containerdisk
          containerDisk:
            image: quay.io/kubevirt/cirros-container-disk-demo
        - name: cloudinitdisk
          cloudInitNoCloud:
            userDataBase64: SGkuXG4=
---
apiVersion: "k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1"
kind: NetworkAttachmentDefinition
metadata:
  name: bridge-test
spec:
  config: '{
      "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
      "name": "bridge-test",
      "type": "bridge",
      "master": "kvbr0",
      "mode": "bridge",
      "ipam": {
        "type": "static",
        "addresses": [
          {
            "address": "10.120.224.45/23",
            "gateway": "10.120.225.1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }'

On the host I have bridge kvbr0 that is also in the 10.120.224.0/23 network.
This applies successfully. After I start the VM using virtctl start testvm, running virtctl console testvm shows nothing. kubectl get vmi shows testvm in phase Scheduling.
